# Parse Kit build project issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, parsekit

I have downloaded Parse Kit from this [link](http://code.google.com/p/todparsekit/source/checkout)

I am using Xcode 4.5 and i am trying to build Parse Kit project, but it is finishing with issues for example like below:

it is description of issue on the line below in ParseKit's sources: `Format not a string literal and no format arguments. But I notice that I have not changed any just build it and run. Anybody has got the same issue?`

```
[[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInFunction:functionString file:fileString lineNumber:(NSInteger)[lineNumber longValue] description:descriptionString];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added nil to this line and it works

```
[[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInFunction:functionString file:fileString lineNumber:(NSInteger)[lineNumber longValue] description:descriptionString, nil];
```

because method get this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Fix is
[[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInFunction:functionString file:fileString lineNumber:(NSInteger)[lineNumber longValue] description:@"%@", descriptionString];